# How IConnectivityManager.getMobileProvisioningUrl() on Android 4.4.2 is implemented

Tags: android, android-4.4-kitkat

I've been trying to understand how `IConnectivityManager.getMobileProvisioningUrl()` looks up for a URL, but all I found in [`ConnectivityManager.java`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/android-4.4.2_r1/core/java/android/net/ConnectivityManager.java) is calling underlying `mService.getMobileProvisioningUrl()`.

Where can I find effective `getMobileProvisioningUrl()` implementation?

Answer (score 0):

Android source code is available publicly: http://source.android.com/ and ConnectivityManager.java is part of it i.e. https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base.git/+/android-4.3_r2.1/core/java/android/net/ConnectivityManager.java

Comment: Yes, I've seen that and it doesn't have effective implementation of `getMobileProvisioningUrl()` (besides being a link to a different version I'm asking about).